# Perl-based HTML id attribute generator

Tags: html, perl

I have a web page containing a table of information sourced from a back-end database. In this table is a (usually) unique key, provided by a third party which I have little control of.

Because HTML `id` attributes are case insensitive, must be unique, and can contain only certain characters, I've resorted to using an MD5 hash to create them based on the unique database keys. The keys themselves are far from meeting HTML `id` tag standards.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

use Digest::MD5 qw(md5_hex);

my @extens = qw( g h i j k l m n o p q );

sub GenHTMLid {

    my $id = md5_hex( $_[0] );

    # HTML 4.01 does not allow ID's that begin with numbers
    $id =~ s/(^[0-9])/$extens[$1]/;

    return $id;
}
```

This seems to work for most cases, but isn't ideal for my situation due to the length (32 characters) of the keys being created.

My guess is that a generator which used the entire set of lower-case alphabetic characters would likely need far fewer characters to be generally unique.

I've been searching through CPAN and the internet for a module to create these tags, but haven't found one. Does anyone happen to know of one, or have a solution that would require far fewer characters?

Additional Info:  The DB engine is Sybase.  The keys (provided by 3rd party) are 6 to 7 fields, separated by a slash (/) character.  Though many are the fields may only contain specific values, two of the fields are 'free hand', and often contain characters you would not want to appear in an HTML id tag, like: ( ) [ ] < > ! ~ $ % , # and 'space'.  The entire key (all fields and separators) are stored in a simple varchar, after some very minor translation - to prevent Sybase from complaining.  The 'id' tag is required by 3rd party web apps, so I can not easily change it to 'data'.

Comment: Could you please elaborate on why you're using these IDs directly in your HTML? What are you trying to do on the page that requires assigning IDs to HTML table cell elements?

Comment: @ThisSuitIsBlackNot The page is being updated dynamically via calls to back-end Perl and Javascript programs, and also using a JSON based caching system.  The updates are being performed via these Element IDs.

Comment: Instead of using HTML `id`s, I would recommend using [HTML5 data-* attributes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Using_data_attributes). (You can still use them in HTML4, they are simply treated as regular attributes.) `data-` attributes do not have to be unique, and would be more semantically correct than shoving actual application data into `id`s.

Comment: What database engine are you using? And what do the database keys look like?

Comment: Just noticed your edit vis-a-vis the `id` being required. I posted an answer using `data-` attributes anyway, just in case somebody in the future doesn't have the same constraints as you do.

Comment: Just out of curiosity, though...it seems like you can set the `id` to anything you want, since you're not using the database keys directly. How does that prevent you from using `data-` attributes to hold the database keys and simply setting the `id`s to something else, like `row1`, `row2`, etc.?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't mind the increased memory footprint of [@choroba's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26410843/100754), I would recommend you go with that.

Otherwise, you can take a hint from git's usage of commit hashes: Most of the time, the first seven hex digits are enough.

For example,

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use strict;
use warnings;
use Digest::SHA1 qw(sha1_hex);

run();

sub run {
    my %id;
    for my $byte (0 .. 255) {
        $id{ GenHTMLid(chr $byte) } = 1;
    }
    print scalar keys %id, "\n";
}

sub GenHTMLid { 'id' . substr( sha1_hex( $_[0] ), 0, 8) }
```

will print `256`. I do not know what your database key space looks like. If we had some idea, we could test for collisions in that key space.

If we can rule out collisions, the version of `GenHTMLid` would give you a bijection between database keys and HTML id's without the memory footprint of a lookup table.

Answer (score 0):

You can just generate strings from `a` to `zzzz` etc. and keep the mapping in hash:

```
{   # closure
    my %id;
    my $generate = 'a';
    sub GetId {
        my $dbkey = shift;
        return $id{$dbkey} ||= $generate++;
    }
}
```

Just run `GetId($key)` to get always the same id for the same $key.

Answer (score 0):

The HTML `id` attribute is supposed to *uniquely* identify an element in the HTML document. It doesn't make sense to use it for rows in a table that may not be unique. In fact, it doesn't really make sense to assign `id`s to table rows in the first place, since tables are usually used for displaying data uniformly; there are special HTML elements for the exceptions, which include table headers, footers, and column groups.

I would recommend using [HTML5 `data-*` attributes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Using_data_attributes) instead. (You can still use them in HTML4, they are simply treated as regular attributes.) `data-*` attributes can be used to associate data with a particular HTML element, even if the data doesn't give any particular semantic meaning to the markup. The values of `data-*` attributes do not have to be unique and are not limited to letters, digits, hyphens, underscores, colons, and periods like `id`s are.

In browsers that support them, `data-*` attributes are trivial to access with vanilla JavaScript using the `dataset` property:

*HTML*

```html
<div id="foo" data-uuid="12345"></div>
```

*JavaScript*

```javascript
var foo  = document.querySelector("#foo");
var uuid = foo.dataset.uuid; // "12345"
```

There are also polyfills that allow you to emulate the `dataset` property on browsers that don't support it.

With jQuery, you can use the [`.data()`](http://api.jquery.com/data/) method:

```javascript
$( "#foo" ).data( "uuid" ); // "12345"
```

Below is a more complete (runnable) example. It changes the background color of a particular row in a table based on the value of a `data-*` attribute. Note that instead of simply changing the background color, the value of this attribute could be used in an AJAX request and sent back to the server.

```js
$(function() {
  var highest;

  $("tr").each(function() {
    var userid = $(this).data("userid");

    if (userid != null) {
      if (highest == null) {
        highest = $(this);
      } else if (userid > highest.data("userid")) {
        highest = $(this);
      }
    }
  });

  // Highlight the row with the highest user ID
  highest.css("background-color", "red");
});
```

```css
td {
  outline: solid black 1px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<table>
  <caption>Stack Overflow users who need more sleep</caption>
  <tr>
    <th>Username</th>
    <th>Reputation</th>
  </tr>
  <tr data-userid="1733163">
    <td>Miller</td>
    <td>26,621</td>
  </tr>
  <tr data-userid="223226">
    <td>mpapec</td>
    <td>31,846</td>
  </tr>
  <tr data-userid="589924">
    <td>ikegami</td>
    <td>139,368</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```